# Functional analysis question about topological closure of a subset

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, normed-spaces

Let $E$ be a normed space and $F$ be a subset of $E$ and $x\in E$. Define $\text{dist}(x,F)=\inf_{y\in F}\Vert x-y\Vert.$ Show that
$$\overline{F}=\{x\in E:\text{dist}(x,F)=0\}.$$

My proof:

The topology generated on $E$ by the norm has the basis consisting of open balls
$\small B(x,\epsilon)=\{y\in E: \Vert x-y\Vert<\epsilon\}$ for all $x\in E$ and for all $\epsilon\in\Bbb R^+.$

If $x\in\overline F$, then for any $\epsilon>0$, $B(x,\epsilon)\cap F\neq\emptyset$ and so there exists $y\in F$ such that $\Vert x-y\Vert<\epsilon$. Hence, $x\in
\{x\in E:\text{dist}(x,F)=0\}.$

Conversely, if $x\in\{x\in E:\text{dist}(x,F)=0\}$, then for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $y\in F$ such that $\Vert x-y \Vert<\epsilon.$ But that means for any $\epsilon>0$, $B(x,\epsilon)\cap F\neq\emptyset$. Hence $x\in\overline F.$ Q.E.D.

Is my proof okay? What can I add more?

Also, is the definition of infimum important here? I didn't use it.

Thanks for your reading.

Comment: The relevance of the infimum instead of minimum is that the points in the closure might not be in $F$. Just like the closure of $(0,1)$ is $[0,1]$; you don't have $0,1 \in (0,1)$ but $\text{dist}(0,(0,1)) = 0 = \text{dist}(1,(0,1))$ just as you proved.

Answer (score 1):

The use of the infimum is essential to the definition $\text{dist}(x,F) := \inf_{y\in F}\|x-y\|$, because for a given $x\in E$, there is, in general, no $y_{0}\in F$ such that $\|x - y_{0}\| = \inf_{y\in F}\|x-y\|$. The existence of such a $y_{0}$ can be guaranteed when $E$ is finite-dimensional and $F$ is closed, but not in general.

You did make use of the infimum while you were using that $z\in \{x\in E:\text{dist}(x,F) = 0\}$ is equivalent to the property that for all $\varepsilon >0$, there is some $y\in F$ such that $\|z-y\| < \varepsilon$.

In addition, you should be careful writing $x\in \{ x\in E : \text{dist}(x,F) = 0 \}$, because you are using the variable $x$ both as a fixed element of $E$ outside of the set, and as a variable which ranges over all the elements of $E$ in the set.

It is also worth mentioning that this result holds in metric spaces with an essentially identical proof.